# fetching email addresses ios device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

I would like to fetch all email addresses that are stored on the device. I can fetch  addresses from contacts (using AddressBook framework) but the device stores more. I can create a new email on the device and I got some kind of completition when entering the email address (when connected to the web I can get even more, so basically some of them are downloaded dynamically and some of them are stored locally).

Is there an api to fetch all those email addresses? Or maybe the only emails I can get are those from contact book?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'completion' you talk of is only available within the applications cache and not via any public API's.
As far as I know, only contacts available in your contacts via ABAddressBook will be accessible to your own apps.

Comment: i believe it could be done in previous versions of ios, as written here: [link](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/) i hoped it still can be done.

Comment: I see, cool. had forgotten about the .db file. Its not possible to access in iOS6 I'm afraid. Think it went in in iOS5. If you find a way please post :-)